# problem with readme.txt description and youtube video

Tags: wordpress.org, readme

I am the author of the [Bitcoin and Altcoin Wallets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wallets/) plugin and I'm facing an issue with [my readme.txt file](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wallets/tags/2.2.2/readme.txt).

I would like to show a video and a text description, like other plugins do.

I have entered a description in the description section and a youtube video, as you can see in the link above. The video shows just fine in the plugin page, but if you search for the plugin, in the search results list the description is not shown. Instead the youtube URL is shown in its place.

My first thought was to see what others do in this situation, but as far as I can tell, I'm doing exactly the same as [this](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/gallery-video/tags/2.1.1/readme.txt) and [this](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/youtube-video-player/tags/1.9.1/readme.txt):

First the description paragraph, then the `== Description ==` header, then the YouTube URL. The description text shows correctly in search result summaries for these other plugins.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? The validator was not of much help as it does not give you a preview of plugin summaries.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question, I thought I found the problem, but after reviewing your readme that is exactly the same.

Comment: instead of posting off-topic questions here, it will be much more productive for you to ask the people who actually know amd can help on the #meta slack

Comment: See Ottos answer, this isn't a WP development problem, it's specific to how WordPress.org is implemented, and you should go to the .org Meta team

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a bug in the parser with regards to short descriptions. I've just been fixing them manually for now when I run across them.

Regardless of the reason for the error, you get much better results if you ask the plugins team directly instead of posting somewhere else.

We have an email address. plugins @ wordpress.org. You can use that to ask the team with admin access, and they can give you real answers. Asking here is unlikely to get a real answer, unless somebody like me happens to stop by and notice the question.

As for your plugin, I fixed it manually. See how simple it can be when you go to the source?

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of this. Will make sure to use the proper channels in the future.

Comment: Everybody who has a plugin in the directory knows that email address, because that is the one that emailed them saying their plugin was approved in the first place.  That's a real email address, not a fake one. You can reply to it, and get an actual response from an actual human being.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress [readme.txt](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-your-readme-txt-works/) uses customized version of the [MarkDown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) . Here is the [Markdown:Syntax](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Actually, you didn't add the Youtube video according to the syntax.
[MarkDown supports 2 types of links: inline and reference.](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link) 
You can refer a website like this:

```
This is [an example](http://example.com/ "Title") inline link.

[This link](http://example.net/) has no title attribute.
```

Output will be:

```
<p>This is <a href="http://example.com/" title="Title">
an example</a> inline link.</p>

<p><a href="http://example.net/">This link</a> has no
title attribute.</p>
```

The proper, way to add the Youtube video in the readme file is:

[youtube https://www.youtube.com]

I have updated your readme.txt file according to the WordPress and MarkDown Syntax:

=== Plugin Name === 
Contributors: nameofcontributon
Donate link: https://flattr.com/profile/dashed-slug
Tags: wallet, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, altcoin, coin, money, e-money, e-cash, deposit, withdraw, account, API
Requires at least: 3.8
Tested up to: 4.7.4
Stable tag: 2.2.3
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

Turn your blog into a bank: Let your users deposit, withdraw, and transfer bitcoins and altcoins on your site.

== Description ==

[youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dbkKHhEzRQ]

#### Turn your blog into a bank: Let your users deposit, withdraw, and transfer bitcoins and altcoins on your site.

```
You can highlight the text in two ways:

 1. ### Highlighted syntax.

 2. <strong>Highlighted syntax.</strong>
```

You can also use the [HTML in the readme.txt](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) file.

You can download the updated readme.txt file from the [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cv19fjw6oyhuzh/readme.txt?dl=0).

Hopefully, it will solve the problem. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't mention this, but I had already tried what you suggest in my previous version, and I had faced the same problem. This is why I then tried emulating the readme files from other plugins where the video and description shows correctly. See here: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wallets/tags/2.2.1/readme.txt . This is frustrating, because I can only test once per release, and it's against the guidelines to do many trivial releases in sequence. I guess I can do more tries by forcing an svn retag but it's an ugly hack. Let me know if you have any more ideas.