# Updating a WP Plugin SVN not showing on Wordpress Website or Zip

Tags: plugin-development, svn, version-control, readme

Thanks in advance for any help given, I have been happily developing a plugin over the past while and have recently released the first public versions on the WP site. I have however encountered a frustrating issue with the SVN updating. I had 5.0.0 through to 5.2.0 in the tags folder, I am not sure what has happened, but I somehow managed to lose all of those tagged versions.

Now I have kind of started from scratch, uploaded the plugin to the trunk folder and have recreated the tags folder with only 1 tagged stable version in it.

The WP site is still not seeing or reading from the trunk or the stable version and is stuck on a version that according to Trac no longer even exists.

PLEASE HELP!

Plugin URL - https://wordpress.org/plugins/property-drive/

Comment: The best way to get support for plugins in the plugin directory is to send an email to *plugins @ wordpress.org* https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/266497/2807

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for the tip, I have already done this, I have been scouring the net trying to find an answer that gets here a little quicker :(

Comment: Right on! I've seen a few plugin repo questions pop up here recently and wanted to steer you in the right direction in case you were not aware of that email address. Thought that question I linked to was interesting because the issue stemmed from a bug in the repo that nobody without inside knowledge would be able to solve.

Comment: My bad, I completely didn't see your link lol. I just checked out that post, I hadn't come across that one yet! Very interesting, unfortunately I have literally tried everything I can think of. I pretty certain it is of my own doing but I just cannot figure out how to either roll back to a fresh repo as it were or fix whats wrong! I have a major update to my plugin which is a fairly crucial one and I can't get it up there! Bad times!